# basemap & contourf, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, contourf

I have a set of satellite data [file here](https://ufile.io/zo8vh), I created a grid for lat & lon and a 2D array for Ozone values.

I know that in order to plot the contourf of the data in a map I need the projection coordinates, but I can't get find a way around it as my grid is not square (144x24). I am covering the geographical area (0 to 360; -30 to 30) and I require square pixels.

The data is quite long to post it but this is my code so far,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
%matplotlib inline

path = '/home/rafaella/month_files_CSV/O3_COLUMNS_MATCHED_fv0005_200306.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=1)

df = pd.read_csv(path, delim_whitespace=True)
lat = np.array(df['AVG_LAT'])
lon = np.array(df['AVG_LON'])
toc = np.array(df['TROP_COL'])

#new grid for lon[0,360] lat[-30,30]

lomin = 0
lomax = 360
lamin = -30
lamax = 30
stp   = 2.5

loc_lon = np.zeros(int((lomax-lomin)/stp))
loc_lat = np.zeros(int((lamax-lamin)/stp))

for i in range(0,len(loc_lon)):
    loc_lon[i] = i*stp +lomin

for j in range(0,len(loc_lat)):
    loc_lat[j] = j*stp +lamin

mtoc_local = np.zeros((len(loc_lon),len(loc_lat))) 
sdtoc_local = np.zeros((len(loc_lon),len(loc_lat))) 
mtoc_local[:,:] = np.nan      
sdtoc_local[:,:] = np.nan

for i in range (0, len(loc_lon)):
    for j in range (0,len(loc_lat)):
        ix = np.where((lon>=loc_lon[i])& (lat>=loc_lat[j]) & (lon<loc_lon[i]+stp) & (lat<loc_lat[j]+stp))[0] 
        mtoc_local[i,j]=np.nanmean(toc[ix]) 
        sdtoc_local[i,j]=np.nanstd(toc[ix])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=0,llcrnrlat=-30, urcrnrlon=360.,urcrnrlat=30.,\
        rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
        resolution='l',projection='merc',\
        lat_0=0,lon_0=-30.,lat_ts=30.)

map.drawcoastlines()
# draw parallels
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-30,30,10),labels=[1,1,0,1])
# draw meridians
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,20),labels=[1,1,0,1])

map = plt.contourf(loc_lon, loc_lat , mtoc_local.T, vmin=210, vmax=350,  cmap='RdPu')
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', ticks=[200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 300, 320, 340] )
plt.title('Tropical TOC monthly mean 06,2009')

plt.show()
```

It plots very well the map OR the data but not both. here an image of both separately
 [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmojJ.png)

[real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBqa.png)

I am very new to python, I started a month ago, so it is still not familiar to me all the functions and libraries.

Comment: Can you post an example of either your csv file, or the lat/lon/toc variables? very hard to help without some sample data that [recreates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure, but the problem is with the projected coordinates, I am not using the coordinates given in the data, but a grid.

Comment: I think that Basemap does not like longitude in the range of [0,360] but rather [-180, 180]. Not sure if this is the root cause of your problems though.

Comment: Your link to the data does not seem to work.

Comment: I changed the link, I hope this works

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two problems. First you have to apply the projection on your coordinates which is done using `x,y = map(lon, lat)`. However, this will raise an error in your case since the dimensions of loc_lon and loc_lat are different. Instead of passing x and y vectors to the contourf function you can pass arrays with the same shape as z (mtoc_local.T). You can use `np.meshgrid` to create those. Long story short, replace the line with the contourf command with the following three lines

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(loc_lon, loc_lat)
x,y = map(X,Y)
map = plt.contourf(x, y , mtoc_local.T, vmin=210, vmax=350,  cmap='RdPu')
```

and the result looks like this
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It did work. I also tried Cartopy and works fine aswell.

Comment: @RafaellaChiarella The proper way to thank is clicking the accept button.

Comment: what's the 'map' here as in python?